# Packing Node and MongoDB in an App to Install in a Desktop.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, electron

I need to install my app on Windows and Mac, which are the main package that i need to do that, also need firts install node and mongoDb in order my app can run.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to install MongoDB with a Node.js app,  but you could use [TingoDB](http://www.tingodb.com). It's a drop-in replacement for MongoDB (it uses exactly the same API) except that you don't need to run a separate database server.

If you switch to it, you can use software like [Nexe](https://jaredallard.me/nexe/) or [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com).

Comment: He has tagged Electron which suggests an desktop app with UI. I would recommend NeDB as it is designed for use with Electron and uses a subset of MongoDB's API.

Comment: TingoDB (just like any other package) is compatible with Electron. NeDB looks perfect for this though! You should post this as an answer.